# Pictures won't copy to thumb drive, "Duplicate image error" when none exists, empty folder

Tags: python, camera

I used a raspberry pi 3 running Pixel to do a timelapse image capture using a python script that runs @reboot through crontab.

```
@reboot sudo sh Timelapse.sh
```

This runs a python script that camera.capture_continuous({timestamp}) with a delay.

The problem is the images it produced will not copy to a thumb drive.  I can copy them to any system folder, I can copy NON-picture files to the thumb drive from the same folder, but pictures generated by the script return an error that there is already a file with the same name, skip or rename.  The destination folder is empty.  If I try to rename, it still gives the same error for the renamed file.  If I change permissions, same error.  If I copy the files to another directory and then try to transfer, same error.

Why can I move these .jpeg files around the RPi, but cannot transfer to removable media?  Any other file can transfer.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l ~/Timelapse/ | head
total 1050088
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 708149 Dec  8 08:24 img2016-12-08 08:24:26.848877.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 711502 Dec  8 08:26 img2016-12-08 08:26:27.313694.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 714928 Dec  8 08:28 img2016-12-08 08:28:27.774978.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 710369 Dec  8 08:30 img2016-12-08 08:30:28.237754.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 717713 Dec  8 08:32 img2016-12-08 08:32:28.733929.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 722583 Dec  8 08:34 img2016-12-08 08:34:29.197001.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 711187 Dec  8 08:36 img2016-12-08 08:36:29.656713.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 720996 Dec  8 08:38 img2016-12-08 08:38:30.115113.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 709879 Dec  8 08:40 img2016-12-08 08:40:30.573294.jpg


pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/5D19-A6AD $ cp ~/Timelapse/img2016-12-10\ 08\:54\:35.395334.jpg ./
cp: cannot create regular file ‘./img2016-12-10 08:54:35.395334.jpg’: Invalid argument

pi@raspberrypi:/media/pi/5D19-A6AD $ sudo fdisk -l
#...cropped
Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1         8192  2289062  2280871  1.1G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      2289063 62521343 60232281 28.7G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5      2293760  2359293    65534   32M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6      2359296  2488319   129024   63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p7      2490368 62521343 60030976 28.6G 83 Linux
```

I was able to copy images from another timelapse series to the same usb drive yesterday, and I can move any file that isn't from the timelapse series to the drive.  The only files that won't move are the images.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: ...and the filesystem on the thumb drive is?  Could you edit your question to include a `ls -l` of the to and from directories as well as the commands you issue in the console?

Comment: Added info to the original question

Comment: Does that say what the thumb drive filesystem is?  I presume it's on 5D19-A6AD but that doesn't tell me much apart from it's probably FAT.  Does it accept file names with spaces and colons and multiple dots?  Try copying a file with an ordinary name such as `f2017.jpg`.

Comment: Mm, it's the colon.  Should've seen that.  Thanks!